# Efficiency of conditional boolean returns, c/c++

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, conditional-statements

Someone recently has pointed out to me that

```
int n = some number;
return n == 5;
```

is faster than

```
return n == 5 ? true : false;
```

which is also faster than

```
if (n == 5) return true;
else return false;
```

Is this so and why?

Comment: No, that's pulled out of a hat. Any decent compiler will generate (virtually) the same code for either. Use what you think reads best.

Comment: "Someone recently..." yes,, the web is full of stories told by "someone... recently...". Are they true? What do you believe is the best way to find out what is the reality? Asking "someone else"? Why not simply look at the generated assembly, profile a real world program? And even if the given code results in different time consumtion, how important will this in any real world application? What is evaluate and passing back a bool in comparison to get a memory block of the heap? My hint: Fear for problems but not for useless discussions :-)

Comment: Yes, it's faster to read and understand, for humans. No, it will not execute any faster in a machine.

Comment: Which expression is more clear to you? I find the latter unnecessarily verbose

Comment: You can test these claims yourself by looking at the compiler output for examples including these snippets (with optimizations turned on). For example on: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: BTW: "`return n == 5 ? true : false;` This is fully obscure! Calculate a bool and decide what to put back with the exact same value as the decision is before. If you like such kind of indirections, you can write endless terms of such useless code... readable? The compiler will nail it down to the comparison and drop the rest...

Comment: @MatG I think the first one is much cleaner but for people that are just starting out, the latter might be more understandable.
For context, I was asked to optimize the latter in an interview and all I could come up with was the one with the ternary operator.

Comment: In `if (n == 5)\n return true;\n else\n return false;` could have the slight advantage that breakpoints can be set on the true and false return statements (provided no optimization). Besides of that, I prefer the shortest form `return n==5;`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it can be answered definitively for all possible cases.
Most modern compilers would generate identical code for all of your examples because they are smart enough to see that the control graph is identical. So in practise you would not see any difference. You should code to make the code understandable, the compilers are smart enogh to optimize for speed.